# Integrating $(3x + 1) / x^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate the following equation, but my answer is different from the textbook and I cannot see where I am going wrong:

\begin{align} \int_1^2\frac{ 3x + 1}{x^{1/2}}dx
&=  \int_1^2 \frac{3x}{x^{1/2}}dx +  \int_1^2 \frac{1}{x^{1/2}}dx \\
&=  \int_1^2 3x^{1/2}dx +  \int_1^2 x^{-1/2}dx\\
&= 2x^{3/2}\vert_1^2 + 2x^{1/2}\vert_1^2 
\end{align}

The book has an answer $6\sqrt{2} - 4$, but according to what I have just done the answer is roughly $7.07 - 4 = 3.07$.

Comment: $7.07$ looks a lot like $5\sqrt2$.  I'm guessing you inadvertently dropped the coefficient $2$ from $2x^{1/2}$ when plugging in the upper limit, and got just $\sqrt2$ instead of $2\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align} \int_1^2 3x^{1/2} \,dx + \int_1^2 x^{-1/2}\,dx & = \frac{3x^{3/2}}{{\frac 32}} + \frac{x^{1/2}}{1/2}\Big|_1^2\\ \\
& = 2 x^{3/2} + 2x^{1/2}\Big|_1^2 \\ \\ 
& = 4\sqrt 2 + 2\sqrt 2 - (2 + 2)\\ \\ & = 6\sqrt 2 - 4\end{align}$$

Comment: Can I ask how you got from 2X^3/2 to 4√2 ?

Comment: Sure: $2(2)^{3/2} = = 2(2^3)^{1/2}= 2\sqrt{8} = 2\cdot 2\cdot \sqrt 2= 4\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 4):

You did everything right when finding the indefinite integral! You just did the definite integral wrong.

the integral from 1 to 2 of your function using what you did would be
$$2*\sqrt{2^3}+2*\sqrt{2}-2*\sqrt{1^3}-2*\sqrt{1}=2*\sqrt{8}+2*\sqrt{2}-4=6\sqrt{2}-4$$
which is in fact, the given answer.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from where you left off, which is correct so far...
\begin{align} 2x^{3/2}\vert_1^2 + 2x^{1/2}\vert_1^2&=[2(2\sqrt{2})-2(1)]+[2(\sqrt{2})-2(1)] \\
&=4\sqrt{2}-2+2\sqrt{2}-2 \\
&=6\sqrt{2}-4\end{align}